# Git: Understanding post-receive

Tags: git, githooks, git-post-receive

I'm fairly new to the Git world after moving from SVN recently and I'm trying to understand the `post-receive` hook.

Hopefully I'm correct in saying that this is a server-side hook but how would I use the `post-receive` hook to run a command client-side or is there another hook to achieve this?

---

Eg.

`post-receive` hook runs on server. Sends command to client/committer and that command runs on their computer (eg. echo Commit received.)

---

And sorry if I got this all completely wrong - I'm new to Git.

Comment: [Chapter 7.3 of Pro Git](http://git-scm.com/book/ch7-3.html) is an excellent resource for familiarizing yourself with Git hooks.

Comment: In Pro Git v2, this is now [Chapter 8.3](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm no expert on git hooks as I'm just learning to use them myself, but I would recommend reading this for some background/context on the hooks:

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

In answer to your specific question, you wouldn't use a post-receive hook to run a command on the client side, you would instead use one of the client side hooks like:

post-commit

which would be I believe the client side equivalent of post-receive (i.e. after the entire commit process has completed).

Comment: I have read your link, but cannot find why it is not executed. I have set permissions to 777. Only one guy suggests to check what transport protocol is git using, but I can't find how to check that

Comment: It sounds like you need to ask your own separate question. This question was about understanding which hook to use on the client side to run a command after a successful commit.

Comment: I figured it out. By word server it meant bitbucket or some server like this. I was trying in my server. But my server was a client in relation to bitbucket. So thats why it was not working. I think that should be more clearly documented, because usually when developer thinks about server - its a linux server where he puts website files. But for that I used post-merge command , so when I run git pull on my server, it merges and executes a hook.